# NestJS TypeORM mock a datasource of a repository

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to mock out a repository. I don't want to do actual database calls. I (think I) am following the documentation on NestJS, and certain stackoverflow items.

However, when I run the test I get the following error:

```
JwtStrategy › validate › throws an unauthorized exception as user cannot be found
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UserEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If DataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If DataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing DataSource */ ]
  })
```

Now as I understand, it seems that the UserEntityRepository is not properly mocked. As it is the first (index [0]) dependency in the user service class:

**./user.service.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>
    ) {}

    async findOneBy({ username }): Promise<UserEntity> {
        return await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ username })
    }
}
```

**./jwt.strategy.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
      private userService: UserService,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET || config.get('jwt.secret'),
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: JwtPayload) {
    const { username } = payload;
    const user = await this.userService.findOneBy({username});

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

**./jwt.strategy.spect.ts**

```js
const mockUserRepositoryFactory = jest.fn(() => ({
  findOneBy: jest.fn(entity => entity),
}));

describe('JwtStrategy', () => {
  let jwtStrategy: JwtStrategy;
  let userService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UserModule],
      providers: [
        JwtStrategy,
        UserService,
        // shouldn't this correctly provide the datasource?
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(UserEntity),
          useFactory: mockUserRepositoryFactory,
        },

      ]
    }).compile();

    jwtStrategy = await module.get<JwtStrategy>(JwtStrategy);
    userService = await module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });

  describe('validate', () => {
    it('validates and returns user based on JWT payload', async () => {
      const user = new UserEntity();
      user.username = 'TestUser';

      userService.findOneBy.mockResolvedValue(user);
      const result = await jwtStrategy.validate({ username: 'TestUser' });
      expect(userService.findOneBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ username: 'TestUser' });
      expect(result).toEqual(user);
    });

    it('throws an unauthorized exception as user cannot be found', async () => {
      userService.findOneBy.mockResolvedValue(null);
      expect(jwtStrategy.validate({ username: 'TestUser' })).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException);
    });
  });
});
```

**===== Update**

Created a minimal setup in a Codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-benz-kve4eq?file=/test/jwt.test.js

But somehow the test tab isn't showing in the sandbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to mock DataSource (if you like you can create a separate file)

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

// @ts-ignore
export const dataSourceMockFactory: () => MockType<DataSource> = jest.fn(() => ({
  <mock_function>: jest.fn(),
}));

export type MockType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<{}>;
};
```

Then create a test file

```
describe('---MSG---', () => {
...
  let dataSourceMock: MockType<DataSource>
...
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [<CONTROLLERS>],
      providers: [ <PROVIDERS>
        { provide: DataSource, useFactory: dataSourceMockFactory }],
    }).compile()
...
    dataSourceMock = module.get(DataSource);
...
  })

  describe('---MSG---', () => {
    it('---MSG---', async () => {
      await <Call mock function>
      expect(dataSourceMock.<DataSource mocked function>).toBeCalled();
    });
  })
```

Comment: <mock_function>: jest.fn() getting error for this. Tried let mock_function = any it didn't work.

Comment: <mock_function> need to be call await <Call mock function> here - test file

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are calling `findOneBy` in your service but mocked the `findOne` repository method.

Either you have to mock the `findOne` method of your service or `findOneBy` of your repository. In the current approach, you mock the repository. The solution for this use case would look like this:

```
const mockUserRepositoryFactory = jest.fn(() => ({
  // Change here from findOne to findOneBy
  findOneBy: jest.fn(entity => entity),
}));

describe('JwtStrategy', () => {
  let jwtStrategy: JwtStrategy;
  let userService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [UserModule],
      providers: [
        JwtStrategy,
        UserService,            {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(UserEntity),
          useFactory: mockUserRepositoryFactory,
        },

      ]
    }).compile();

    jwtStrategy = await module.get<JwtStrategy>(JwtStrategy);
    userService = await module.get<UserService>(UserService);
  });

  describe('validate', () => {
    it('validates and returns user based on JWT payload', async () => {
      const user = new UserEntity();
      user.username = 'TestUser';

      // change findOne to findOneBy here as well
      userService.findOneBy.mockResolvedValue(user);
      const result = await jwtStrategy.validate({ username: 'TestUser' });
      expect(userService.findOneBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ username: 'TestUser' });
      expect(result).toEqual(user);
    });

    it('throws an unauthorized exception as user cannot be found', async () => {
      userService.findOneBy.mockResolvedValue(null);
      expect(jwtStrategy.validate({ username: 'TestUser' })).rejects.toThrow(UnauthorizedException);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Good one. I've updated my answer to match. But it also does not solve the problem sadly.