# How would I mock the DataSource from TypeORM in NestJS Jest tests?

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to write tests for a small project in NestJS. Here is the relevant code for context:

`dummy.controller.ts`

```js
@Controller(UrlConstants.BASE_URL + 'dummy')
export class DummyContoller {
    constructor(
        private readonly sessionService: SessionService,
    ) { }

    @Get('validateSession')
    async checkValidateSession(@Query('sessionId') sessionId: string) {
        const session = await this.sessionService.validateSession(sessionId);
        console.log(session);

        return { message: "OK" };
    }
}
```

`session.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
    constructor(
        private readonly sessionRepo: SessionRepository,
        private readonly accountRepo: AccountRepository
    ) { }

    @WithErrorBoundary(AuthCodes.UNKNOWN_LOGIN_ERROR)
    async validateSession(sessionId: string) {
        const session = await this.sessionRepo.findOneBy({ sessionId });
        if (!session || this.isSessionExpired(session)) {
            session && await this.sessionRepo.remove(session);
            throw new HttpException({
                code: AuthCodes.SESSION_TIMEOUT,
                message: AuthMessages.SESSION_TIMEOUT
            }, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
        }

        return session;
    }
    ...
}
```

`session.repository.ts` (Any repository)

```js
@Injectable()
export class SessionRepository extends Repository<Session> {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {
        super(Session, dataSource.createEntityManager())
    }
    ... 
}
```

This is how I wrote my test (this is my first time writing a test using Jest and I am not really experienced in writing tests in general):

```js
describe('DummyController', () => {
    let dummyContoller: DummyContoller;
    let sessionService: SessionService;
    let sessionRepo: SessionRepository;
    let accountRepo: AccountRepository;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
            controllers: [DummyContoller],
            providers: [SessionService, SessionRepository, AccountRepository]
        }).compile();

        dummyContoller = module.get<DummyContoller>(DummyContoller);
        sessionService = module.get<SessionService>(SessionService);
        sessionRepo = module.get<SessionRepository>(SessionRepository);
        accountRepo = module.get<AccountRepository>(AccountRepository);
    })

    describe('checkValidateSession', () => {
        it('should return valid session', async () => {
            const sessionId = "sessionId1";
            const session = new Session();
            jest.spyOn(sessionService, 'validateSession').mockImplementation(async (sessionId) => session);

            expect(await dummyContoller.checkValidateSession(sessionId)).toBe(session);
        })
    })
})
```

Upon running the test, I encounter:

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SessionRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If DataSource is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If DataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing DataSource */ ]
      })
```

I looked this problem and I came across a number of solutions but most of them had `@InjectRepository()` instead of creating a separate Repository class where they would provide `getRepositoryToken()` and then use a mock factory [[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73019162/nestjs-typeorm-mock-a-datasource-of-a-repository). I couldn't find a way to make this work.

Another solution suggested using an in-memory database solution [[Link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70521273/how-to-unit-test-a-custom-repository-of-typeorm-in-nestjs). But this felt more like a hack rather than a solution.

How can I test the above setup?

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this comment](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/363#issuecomment-360105413), I was able to get this working by using the following in the providers in the test:

```js
 providers: [
     SessionService,
     { provide: SessionRepository, useClass: SessionMockRepository },
 ]
```

SessionMockRepository contains a mocked version of all additional functions in that particular repository:

```js
export class SessionMockRepository extends Repository<Session> {
    someFunction = async () => jest.fn();
}
```

Currently, this works for me so I am accepting this. I am still open to more answers if there is a better way to do this.