# Cannot test e2e because Nestjs doesn't resolve dependencies

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have the following error :

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ParametrageRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

My test code :

```
describe("ParametrageController (e2e)", () => {
    let parametrage: INestApplication;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [ParametrageModule],
        }).compile();

        parametrage = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        await parametrage.init();
    });

    it("/ (POST)", () =>
        request(parametrage.getHttpServer())
            .post("/parametrage")
            .send({
                libelle: "GROUPE_TYPE",
                liste: ["TEAM", "SERVICE", "ORGANISATION"],
            })
            .expect(201));
});
```

My module code:

```
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Parametrage])],
    exports: [TypeOrmModule],
    controllers: [ParametrageController],
    providers: [ParametrageService, ParametrageRepository, ParametrageActions, Logger],
})
export class ParametrageModule {}
```

I cannot tel why I have this error since I followed the Nestjs documentation. Maybe I skipped a part I don't know. Maybe it's because of my providers that has parameters in their constructors :

My ParametrageRepository provider :

```
@Injectable()
export class ParametrageRepository
    extends RepositoryStarter<Parametrage, IParametrageListFilter>
    implements IParametrageRepository
{
    constructor(@InjectDataSource() datasource: DataSource) {
        super(datasource.getRepository(Parametrage));
    }
```

I tried to add providers injection :

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [ParametrageModule],
**      providers: [
                 { provide: ParametrageActions, useValue: ParametrageActions },
                 { provide: ParametrageRepository, useValue: ParametrageRepository },
                         { provide: Logger, useValue: Logger ,
                ],**
}).compile();
```

But stil the same error, it didn't solved anything

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have a data source yet, i guess, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73606391/9124424

Answer (score 2):

The error says that it cannot resolve the DataSource. That means that the module has extraneous dependencies which you need provide or mock.

There several ways:

1. Use the a testing database, then you will need to

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [TypeOrm.forRoot(databaseConfig), ParametrageModule],
}).compile();
```

This will inject the DataSource and you will be able to work with the Repositories.

2. You can provide a mock implementation of the DataSource:

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [ParametrageModule],
  provide: [{ provide: DataSource, useFactory: dataSourceMockFactory }]

}).compile();
```

Where `dataSourceMockFactory` is a function that returns the object that has the methods you are using.

3. Instead of importing the whole module you can declare it in place and provide a mock of the repository:

```
const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [ParametrageController],
  providers: [ParametrageService, { provide: ParametrageRepository, useFactory: parametrageRepositoryMockFactory, ParametrageActions, Logger],
```

You will have to provide `parametrageRepositoryMockFactory`. But you don't have to mock all the methods a real `Repository` would provide, just those you are going to need during the test. I.E.:

```
const parametrageRepositoryMockfactory = () => ({
  findAll: () => Promise.resolve([]),
  create: (data) => Promise.resolve(data),
})
```

I would suggest to start with the first approach (testing DB), since it's the easiest one and also gives the real results, not just mocks. Thus it's more reliable.
**note** that you shouldn't use the same DB as for the production, since tests will use it and might create/update/delete data.

The second and third approaches can be used for unit tests, but I don't think it's the right choice in this case.